# Wrapping already typed text in Emacs

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I have a text that I already typed in a text editor, but when I open it in Emacs, so I can keep working o Emacs (Org-Mode), it appears it is not wrapping the lines propperly. The paragraph (or what it is supposed to be a paragraph) appears in a single line, instead of having a line break when reaching the screen limit.

Do you guys know how to reformat these line breaks?

Comment: I am guessing you have a question about using `visual-line-mode` versus the standard wrapping that breaks up words wherever the screen edge is; however, you have not given us a screen shot or a text example that visually depicts the exact issue. As such, we would all be guessing what the issue really is. We are all probably wondering whether it could also be a line ending issue -- e.g., Windows or *nix operating systems. Please consider editing your question to give us something more to work with.  Try typing:  `M-x visual-line-mode` and see if that is what you expect.

Comment: @lawlist: Please post that as an answer. (My guess is that it *is* the answer: Just turn on `visual-line-mode`.)

Answer (score 1):

Emacs has a built-in variable called `word-wrap`, which has a default value of `nil`.  When `word-wrap` is `nil`, long lines are wrapped indiscriminately at the window-edge without consideration as to whether a whole word is visually broken up -- i.e., part of a word may be at the end of the visually wrapped line and part of the word may be at the beginning of the subsequent visually wrapped line.

The most common method of enabling `word-wrap` is to use the built-in `visual-line-mode`:  http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Visual-Line-Mode.html  Visual line mode includes a few other goodies, like remapping certain keyboard shortcuts and pretty bitmap images in the fringes if they are visible in the window.  Enabling `visual-line-mode` can be accomplished a number of ways -- one example is manually:  `M-x visual-line-mode`